# How to return a dynamic result set from a PLPGSQL function?

Tags: dynamic, plpgsql

How to return a dynamic result set from a PLPGSQL function? What can be used instead of `RETURNS SETOF table_name`?

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_query
(
    table_name varchar
)
RETURNS **SETOF table_name**

LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
DECLARE 
    sql varchar;
BEGIN

    /*some code*/

    sql = 'SELECT * FROM '|| table_name;

    /*some code*/

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE sql;
                
END $$;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. Your only choices are:

1. use `RETURNS SETOF record`.

   That works, but you will have to specify the table structure in the query that uses the function, as shown in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS).
2. use `RETURNS SETOF jsonb` and use `to_jsonb` in the query to convert the result rows to `jsonb`

Answer (score 0):

You can return a set of text representation of the record and cast it with your existing type in the select query.

```sql
-- Create and fill sample
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table;

CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    id       BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    int_val  INTEGER,
    text_val TEXT,
    date_val DATE
);

INSERT INTO test_table(int_val, text_val, date_val)
VALUES (1, 'TEST1, TEST', CURRENT_DATE),
       (2, 'TEST2, TEST', CURRENT_DATE),
       (3, 'TEST3, TEST', CURRENT_DATE),
       (4, 'TEST4, TEST', CURRENT_DATE);

--Create Dynamic query
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dynamic_select(p_table_name TEXT);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamic_select(IN p_table_name TEXT)
    RETURNS SETOF TEXT
AS
$$
DECLARE
    v_dynamic_query TEXT;
BEGIN
    --Create query
    v_dynamic_query = FORMAT('SELECT t::TEXT FROM %I t', p_table_name);
    --Execute
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE v_dynamic_query;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Returns text representation of row values of test table
SELECT *
FROM dynamic_select('test_table');

-- Cast to defined type
SELECT (t::TEST_TABLE).*
FROM dynamic_select('test_table') t;
```